# Opening (or converting) photosynth .pano files

Tags: macos, photos, panorama

I have a bunch of panoramas on my laptop that were originally created using Microsoft's Photosynth app for iOS. They were exported to files with a `.pano` extension via [photosynth.net](http://photosynth.net).

**How can I view these files on my Mac, or convert them to a format that I can easily view?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the viewer for Mac here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/photosynth/2016/11/04/photosynth-to-shut-down/